# How to include class from another file(in another folder) - python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

I have a python file in the location 'lib/lib_add_participant.py'.And I declared a class in the file.

Now I want to call the class functions from the file call_participant.py.

I tried this code `from lib/lib_add_participant.py import LibAddParticipant`

Its not worked.Please correct me(I am coming from Ruby).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your file structure is as follows:

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    call_participant.py
    lib/
        __init__.py
        lib_add_participant.py
```

In this case, your `__init__.py` files can be *empty*, if you like (or they can define any number of things - see [this fine answer from Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361124/using-init-py) for more details.

then you can add it by using

```
from .lib.lib_add_participant import LibAddParticipant
```

However, if `call_participant.py` is your end script, then this tactic will not work, because you "can't do a relative import in a non-package", as the interpreter will tell you.  In that case, your best bet (in my opinion, at least) is to make `lib` into a package in your python path (either in your site-packages directory, or in a path referred to by your `pythonpath` environment variable).

Comment: A mistake: there should be `__init__.py` instead of `__init.py`

Comment: Oops!  Good catch - tath's waht I get for tpynig too fsat.

Comment: I didn't created __init__.py file.Now please let me know what all are the contents inside it.I searched google and didn't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `lib` is in a directory listed in your `PYTHONPATH`, try

```
from lib.lib_add_participant import LibAddParticipant
```

Comment: If lib is listed in $PYTHONPATH it would be: `lib_add_participant import LibAddParticipant`. If lib is in one of directories listed in $PYTHONPATH then your code will work, but only if there is an `__init__.py` file there too.