# setup.py not finding pre-installed dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, installation

I am trying to install a package I have written by running

```
 python setup.py install
```

whilst in the package directory. My folder structure is as follows:

```
package
-module
--__init__.py
--parent_class.py
--child_class.py
-setup.py
```

Here '-' denotes the folder level with package being the root directory.

When running the installation works as expected until:

```
Installed c:\users\me\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\package-0.1-py3.7.egg
Processing dependencies for package==0.1
Searching for json
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/json/
Couldn't find index page for 'json' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/
No local packages or working download links found for json
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('json')
```

I don't believe this is an issue with the json package installation as:

1. I know I have it installed (I can run 'import json' in my env)
   and because if I remove it.
2. If i remove 'json' from `install_requires=['pandas', 'numpy', 'datetime', 'os', 'copy', 'json']` it will simply return the same error, this time with the 'copy' and then the 'os' package.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `json` is a built-in module in Python 2 and 3 (e.g., like `open`). Thus, it's usually included in all Python distributions (that is, anyone who has Python probably also has the `json` module).

Thus, you should be able to omit `json` from your requirements (while still importing it in your code). Since `json` is a built-in module, you can assume that anyone who has Python installed will also have `json`.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41466431/pip-install-json-fails-on-ubuntu) that is also about installing the `json` module. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52001009/4451716) notes that minimal Python installs (e.g., `python-minimal` in Ubuntu) may not include `json`, however. You should note that the linked question concerns Python 2 and not 3.

Therefore, if a user lacks `json` on their system, they should be able to install it through their system's package manager (in Linux), and not `pip`. In Windows, I would assume that all Python installations will include built-in modules (though I don't know for certain). Regardless, if a user doesn't have `json` installed, then I think it's up to the user to install it.

The same applies to `os`, `copy`, and `datetime`. Only `pandas` and `numpy` need to be included in your requirements.

You can find a list of built-in modules (for Python 3) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html). Again, the modules listed here are ones that are not hosted on pypi (thus not available through `pip install ...`, `conda install ...`, etc.), but ones that are *usually* included in all Python distributions.

As an aside: this is my first answer here. Please let me know if I can improve it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked (install worked). However the package is not found when I import it :/.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to import `package` (as in your example from your question). You can't really do that, but you should be able to import `module`.

Packaging conventions is a surprisingly complicated topic (at least, to me). You can take a look at [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). Note that, towards the end, the example doesn't import the root directory (`packaging_tutorial`), but only the package/module inside.

Consider renaming `module` to be `package`. Yes, this does mean that 2 folders have the same name, though this is what I do.

Comment: You can also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237806/python-modules-hierarchy-naming-convention). I format my projects with `my_package` as the root level folder and `my_package/my_package` (the actual package that contains `__init__.py`). I place `setup.py` and other packaging files in the root directory. Not sure if this is the best practice, but it seems to be used by several projects: [1](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim), [2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/tree/master/numpy).

Comment: Thanks for this additional advice, i'll check it out now :)