# Python - Get path of root project structure

Tags: python

I've got a python project with a configuration file in the project root. 
The configuration file needs to be accessed in a few different files throughout the project.

So it looks something like: `<ROOT>/configuration.conf` 
`<ROOT>/A/a.py`, `<ROOT>/A/B/b.py` (when b,a.py access the configuration file).

What's the best / easiest way to get the path to the project root and the configuration file without depending on which file inside the project I'm in? i.e without using `../../`? It's okay to assume that we know the project root's name.

Comment: does `<ROOT>/__init__.py` exist?

Comment: Either your configuration file is a python module, and you can easily access it just with an import statement, either it's not a python module and you should put it in a well known location. For example $HOME/.my_project/my_project.conf.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional - It's a JSON file. I need to be able to access it using the path.
Yes. All of the folders include it.

Comment: _ It's okay to assume that we know the project root's name._ Does that mean you know the path to the project? Isn't it just os.path.join(known_root_name, "configuration.conf") then?

Comment: If it's a user configuration I'd generally use something like `os.path.expanduser('~/.myproject/myproject.conf')`. It works on Unix and Windows.

Comment: @tdelaney - I know the project's name (i.e the project root's name) and I know the config file's name and that it's in the root directory. I want to extract the path to the root using the project's name.

Comment: @shookie, I have no idea what "project name" means. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 313):

You can do this how Django does it: **define a variable to the Project Root from a file that is in the top-level of the project.** For example, if this is what your project structure looks like:

```
project/
    configuration.conf
    definitions.py
    main.py
    utils.py
```

In `definitions.py` you can define (this requires `import os`):

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # This is your Project Root
```

Thus, with the **Project Root** known, you can **create a variable that points to the location of the configuration** (this can be defined anywhere, but a logical place would be to put it in a location where constants are defined - e.g. `definitions.py`):

```
CONFIG_PATH = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'configuration.conf')  # requires `import os`
```

Then, you can easily access the constant (in any of the other files) with the import statement (e.g. in `utils.py`): `from definitions import CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: To include the definitions.py file like that, will it be required to add a `__init__.py` file to the root project directory as well ? Should that be correct ? I've just started with python and not sure on the best practices. Thanks.

Comment: @akskap: No, an `__init__.py` will not be required, as that file is only required when defining packages:
*The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.*

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: I am curious, style wise, whether it is acceptable or frowned upon to add these definitions to the `__init.py__` of the root package. It would save creating another file, as well as allow the nicer syntax of `from root_pack import ROOT_DIR, CONFIG_PATH`.

Comment: @Johndt6: the convention is to keep `__init__.py` empty, but that isn't strictly true (it's a convention after all). See this for more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361124/using-init-py

Comment: Here `os` is not by default available. Need to import `os`. So adding the line `import os` would make the answer more complete.

Comment: @akskap I'm not sure if you are correct when saying `__init__.py` is not required. Without it, running a .py file in a sub-directory (i.e `$ python src/foo.py`) returns a ModuleNotFoundError

Comment: Shouldn't it be `ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath('__file__'))`? I'm just pointing out the quote symbols.

Comment: @JavNoor: no - in the example you cited, `os.path.abspath` is calling a string, `'__file__'`. Recall that `__file__` is actually an import attribute that's defined for Python modules. In this case, `__file__` will return the pathname from which the module is loaded. Read more here (see the modules section): https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html

Comment: Thanks @jrd1. I had tried it in jupyter notebook and there it wasn't accepting the input without quotations. But after reading the link you sent it makes sense that quotations shouldn't be there. I suppose these aren't really meant for jupyter.

Comment: @JavNoor: Indeed. Jupyter's behavior is correct - `__file__` applies to modules and python scripts. Jupyter notebooks do not meet this criterion as they're web applications run via a server.

Comment: I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definitions'` error when trying this. I have my project structured like this: `project/src/...` contains all the code, this is where I'm importing `definitions`. The `definitions.py` is next to it in `project/definitions.py`. In my `setup.py `, I define `src` as `package_dir`. Not sure if this has anything to do with it

Comment: @CGFoX: that behavior makes sense - you'll likely need to do a relative import. Also, your question is distinct from the one the OP posed, and can (and _should_) stand on its own. I strongly encourage you to consider posting your own question and solicit feedback from the community in the future.

Comment: `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` is not the root directory. It is the path the the file the code is called from.

Comment: @pookie: Thank you for your comment. I've never said that was the root directory - it's the _project root_. Yes, ROOT_DIR is perhaps a misnomer for the variable name, but given the context of its use and the associated explanation as the project root, the variable's purpose and meaning is clear.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail when run from `project/subdir/newfile.py`?

Comment: @AstroFloyd: It will only fail if subdir is not a sub-package (i.e. it's missing `__init__.py` in the subdir). Without package structuring, Python won't know where ROOT_DIR should be referenced from

Comment: So how would the line `from definitions import CONFIG_PATH` change in my `project/subdir/newfile.py`?  How does Python know to look in `../definitions.py` instead of `definitions.py` from my `subdir/`?  If I do `print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` in my `newfile.py`, it reports `project/subdir/`, not `project/`.  Do I need `__init__.py` somewhere to change that?

Comment: @AstroFloyd: The example shown is for a project root in which `definitions.py` is in the top level. The example you've shown is for a different case within a sub-directory, as calling the statements provided within a file under that heading will only print out the sub-directory root. If your project is structured like a package and the sub-directories are done in a similar manner, then you can call the ROOT_DIR from `definitions.py` in the top-level using an absolute or relative import statement. See this link for more: https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: I understood that to allow relative imports, you need to "turn your code into a package", but it took me a while to figure out that that means **all of** 1) putting an `__init__.py` in the top dir of your code **and** 2) adding the parent directory of the top dir to your `PYTHONPATH` **and** 3) setting the `__package__` variable in your Python program to the name of the directory that contains `__init__.py`.  All is working now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 195):

Other answers advice to use a file in the top-level of the project. This is not necessary if you use `pathlib.Path` and `parent` (Python 3.4 and up). Consider the following directory structure where all files except `README.md` and `utils.py` have been omitted.

```
project
│   README.md
|
└───src
│   │   utils.py
|   |   ...
|   ...
```

In `utils.py` we define the following function.

```
from pathlib import Path

def get_project_root() -> Path:
    return Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

In any module in the project we can now get the project root as follows.

```
from src.utils import get_project_root

root = get_project_root()
```

**Benefits**: Any module which calls `get_project_root` can be moved without changing program behavior. Only when the module `utils.py` is moved we have to update `get_project_root` and the imports (refactoring tools can be used to automate this).

Comment: Any module that's in the root. Calling src.utils from outside of the root shouldn't work. Am I wrong?

Comment: name '__file__' is not defined   , why?

Comment: @LukAron: Be sure to use `__file__` (note underscores) which is a module attribute containing absolute path of module, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: For me, this still doesn't help because you still have to know where src/utils.py is located if you're not in src

Comment: In my case (due to Linux OS?), `Path()` returns the *relative* path.  Hence, I need `Path(__file__).absolute().parent.parent` for this example.

Comment: Awesome, this actually works in my case where I was using python datasets library and on load_dataset, my custom dataset class was being called inside huggingface path (a symlink was being generated of my dataclass file inside the huggingface cache dir). So, I was not able to load other files from cache because files were not in cache but inside project root directory. This helps me there.

Comment: this is the real deal

Answer (score 62):

All the previous solutions seem to be overly complicated for what I think you need, and often didn't work for me. The following one-line command does what you want:

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

Comment: Put that in config.py, at the root of the directory, .. bamn! Yout got yourself a singleton.

Comment: This method presumes you run the application from within the path that it exists. Many "users" have an icon they click from a desktop or can run the app from another directory entirely.

Comment: Still the cleanest way if running from a Non-GUI setup! Thanks @martim

Answer (score 53):

Below Code Returns the path until your project root

```
import sys
print(sys.path[1])
```

Comment: Nice tip! I wonder why nobody upvoted your answer but me :P

Comment: Thanks Daveon Really appreciate that !!

Comment: Unfortunately is not that, simple :P ...take a look at my full solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62510836/267719

Comment: Thanks.. from the shared solution, I was able to get different paths by indexing. Now I just have to select the path I wanted / root path.

```
import sys
print(sys.path[0])
print(sys.path[1])
print(sys.path[2])
print(sys.path[3])
```

Comment: For me sys.path[0] worked.

Comment: this is unreliable.  the root path is always in the list, but the list order changes.

Answer (score 30):

To get the path of the "root" module, you can use:

```
import os
import sys
os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
```

But more interestingly if you have an config "object" in your top-most module you could -read- from it like so:

```
app = sys.modules['__main__']
stuff = app.config.somefunc()
```

Comment: Here `os` is not by default available. Need to import `os`. So adding the line `import os` would make the answer more complete.

Comment: This gives the directory that contains the script that was executed. For example, when running `python3 -m topmodule.submodule.script` it will give `/path/to/topmodule/submodule` instead of `/path/to/topmodule`.

Comment: In context of tests invoked by `pytest` I have got `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest/__main__.py`. RikH's answer is most robust for me (`Path(__file__).parent.parent` in fix-placed module).

Answer (score 22):

A standard way to achieve this would be to use the `pkg_resources` module which is part of the `setuptools` package.  `setuptools` is used to create an install-able python package.

You can use `pkg_resources` to return the contents of your desired file as a string and you can use `pkg_resources` to get the actual path of the desired file on your system.

Let's say that you have a package called `stackoverflow`.

```
stackoverflow/
|-- app
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- resources
    |-- bands
    |   |-- Dream\ Theater
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- King's\ X
    |   |-- Megadeth
    |   `-- Rush
    `-- __init__.py

3 directories, 7 files
```

Now let's say that you want to access the file Rush from a module `app.run`. Use `pkg_resources.resouces_filename` to get the path to Rush and `pkg_resources.resource_string` to get the contents of Rush; thusly:

```
import pkg_resources

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print pkg_resources.resource_filename('resources.bands', 'Rush')
    print pkg_resources.resource_string('resources.bands', 'Rush')
```

The output:

```
/home/sri/workspace/stackoverflow/resources/bands/Rush
Base: Geddy Lee
Vocals: Geddy Lee
Guitar: Alex Lifeson
Drums: Neil Peart
```

This works for all packages in your python path. So if you want to know where `lxml.etree` exists on your system:

```
import pkg_resources

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print pkg_resources.resource_filename('lxml', 'etree')
```

output:

```
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree
```

The point is that you can use this standard method to access files that are installed on your system (e.g pip install xxx or yum -y install python-xxx) and files that are within the module that you're currently working on.

Comment: I like your band choice !

Answer (score 18):

Try:

```
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Simple solution, works for me because my structure was

root->config->conf.py 

I wanted to define the project root in conf.py and root was exactly two levels up from that file.

Comment: This is the best solution so far! Thanks

Answer (score 16):

### Simple and Dynamic!

this solution works on any OS and in any level of directory:

Assuming your project folder name is `my_project`

```
from pathlib import Path

current_dir = Path(__file__)
project_dir = [p for p in current_dir.parents if p.parts[-1]=='my_project'][0]
```

Comment: An alternative to the list comprehension is a generator, and using `Path.name`: `project_dir = next(p for p in current_dir.parents if p.name == "my_project")`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a package that solves that problem: [from-root](https://pypi.org/project/from-root/)

`pip install from-root`

```py
from from_root import from_root, from_here

# path to config file at the root of your project
# (no matter from what file of the project the function is called!)
config_path = from_root('config.json')

# path to the data.csv file at the same directory where the callee script is located
# (has nothing to do with the current working directory)
data_path = from_here('data.csv')
```

Check out the link above and read the readme to see more use cases

Comment: what a wonderful little package!

Answer (score 9):

I've recently been trying to do something similar and I have found these answers inadequate for my use cases (a distributed library that needs to detect project root). Mainly I've been battling different environments and platforms, and still haven't found something perfectly universal.

## Code local to project

I've seen this example mentioned and used in a few places, Django, etc.

```
import os
print(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Simple as this is, it only works when the file that the snippet is in is actually part of the project. **We do not retrieve the project directory, but instead the snippet's directory**

Similarly, the *sys.modules* approach breaks down when **called** from outside the entrypoint of the application, specifically I've observed a child thread cannot determine this without relation back to the '**main**' module. I've explicitly put the import inside a function to demonstrate an import from a child thread, moving it to top level of app.py would fix it.

```
app/
|-- config
|   `-- __init__.py
|   `-- settings.py
`-- app.py
```

app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import threading


def background_setup():
    # Explicitly importing this from the context of the child thread
    from config import settings
    print(settings.ROOT_DIR)


# Spawn a thread to background preparation tasks
t = threading.Thread(target=background_setup)
t.start()

# Do other things during initialization

t.join()

# Ready to take traffic
```

settings.py

```
import os
import sys


ROOT_DIR = None


def setup():
    global ROOT_DIR
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
    # Do something slow
```

Running this program produces an attribute error:

```
>>> import main
>>> Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python2714\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python2714\lib\threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 6, in background_setup
    from config import settings
  File "config\settings.py", line 34, in <module>
    ROOT_DIR = get_root()
  File "config\settings.py", line 31, in get_root
    return os.path.dirname(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

...hence a threading-based solution

## Location independent

Using the same application structure as before but modifying settings.py

```
import os
import sys
import inspect
import platform
import threading


ROOT_DIR = None


def setup():
    main_id = None
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        if t.name == 'MainThread':
            main_id = t.ident
            break

    if not main_id:
        raise RuntimeError("Main thread exited before execution")

    current_main_frame = sys._current_frames()[main_id]
    base_frame = inspect.getouterframes(current_main_frame)[-1]

    if platform.system() == 'Windows':
        filename = base_frame.filename
    else:
        filename = base_frame[0].f_code.co_filename

    global ROOT_DIR
    ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

Breaking this down:
First we want to accurately find the thread ID of the main thread. In Python3.4+ the threading library has `threading.main_thread()` however, everybody doesn't use 3.4+ so we search through all threads looking for the main thread save it's ID. If the main thread has already exited, it won't be listed in the `threading.enumerate()`. We raise a `RuntimeError()` in this case until I find a better solution.

```
main_id = None
for t in threading.enumerate():
    if t.name == 'MainThread':
        main_id = t.ident
        break

if not main_id:
    raise RuntimeError("Main thread exited before execution")
```

Next we find the very first stack frame of the main thread. **Using the cPython specific function** `sys._current_frames()` we get a dictionary of every thread's current stack frame. Then utilizing `inspect.getouterframes()` we can retrieve the entire stack for the main thread and the very first frame.
    current_main_frame = sys._current_frames()[main_id]
    base_frame = inspect.getouterframes(current_main_frame)[-1]
Finally, the differences between Windows and Linux implementations of `inspect.getouterframes()` need to be handled. Using the cleaned up filename, `os.path.abspath()` and `os.path.dirname()` clean things up.

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    filename = base_frame.filename
else:
    filename = base_frame[0].f_code.co_filename

global ROOT_DIR
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

So far I've tested this on Python2.7 and 3.6 on Windows as well as Python3.4 on WSL

Comment: I've tried your "Location independent" code snippet, and I see that it returns a folder where a Python file is executed, not the project root.

Answer (score 7):

I decided for myself as follows.
Need to get the path to 'MyProject/drivers' from the main file.

```
MyProject/
├─── RootPackge/
│    ├── __init__.py
│    ├── main.py
│    └── definitions.py
│
├─── drivers/
│    └── geckodriver.exe
│
├── requirements.txt
└── setup.py
```

definitions.py
Put not in the root of the project, but in the root of the main package

```
from pathlib import Path

ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

Use ROOT_DIR:
main.py

```
# imports must be relative,
# not from the root of the project,
# but from the root of the main package.
# Not this way:
# from RootPackge.definitions import ROOT_DIR
# But like this:
from definitions import ROOT_DIR

# Here we use ROOT_DIR
# get path to MyProject/drivers
drivers_dir = ROOT_DIR / 'drivers'
# Thus, you can get the path to any directory
# or file from the project root

driver = webdriver.Firefox(drivers_dir)
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
```

Then PYTHON_PATH will not be used to access the 'definitions.py' file.

Works in PyCharm:
run file 'main.py' (ctrl + shift + F10 in Windows)

Works in CLI from project root:

```
$ py RootPackge/main.py
```

Works in CLI from RootPackge:

```
$ cd RootPackge
$ py main.py
```

Works from directories above project:

```
$ cd ../../../../
$ py MyWork/PythoProjects/MyProject/RootPackge/main.py
```

Works from anywhere if you give an absolute path to the main file.
Doesn't depend on venv.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me using a standard PyCharm project with my virtual environment (venv) under the project root directory.

Code below isnt the prettiest, but consistently gets the project root. It returns the full directory path to venv from the `VIRTUAL_ENV` environment variable e.g. `/Users/NAME/documents/PROJECT/venv`

It then splits the path at the last `/`, giving an array with two elements. The first element will be the project path e.g. `/Users/NAME/documents/PROJECT`

```
import os

print(os.path.split(os.environ['VIRTUAL_ENV'])[0])
```

Comment: This won't work with setups like anaconda or pipenv, since the virtual environment isn't contained within the project in those cases.

Comment: Clearly the best solution when working with venv. Thank you, it was worth scrolling down.

Answer (score 3):

I struggled with this problem too until I came to this solution.
This is the cleanest solution in my opinion.

In your **setup.py** add "packages"

```
setup(
name='package_name'
version='0.0.1'
.
.
.
packages=['package_name']
.
.
.
)
```

In your **python_script.py**

```
import pkg_resources
import os

resource_package = pkg_resources.get_distribution(
    'package_name').location
config_path = os.path.join(resource_package,'configuration.conf')
```

Comment: Using a virtual environment and installing the package with `python3 setup.py install` it was not pointing to the source code folder anymore, but to the egg inside `~./virtualenv/..../app.egg`. So I had to include the configuration file into the package install.

Answer (score 2):

Just an example: I want to run ***runio.py*** from within ***helper1.py***

Project tree example:

```
myproject_root
- modules_dir/helpers_dir/helper1.py
- tools_dir/runio.py
```

Get project root:

```
import os
rootdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)).rsplit(os.sep, 2)[0]
```

Build path to script:

```
runme = os.path.join(rootdir, "tools_dir", "runio.py")
execfile(runme)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to implement a custom solution because it's not as simple as you might think.
My solution is based on stack trace inspection (`inspect.stack()`) + `sys.path` and is working fine no matter the location of the python module in which the function is invoked nor the interpreter (I tried by running it in PyCharm, in a poetry shell and other...). This is the full implementation with comments:

```
def get_project_root_dir() -> str:
    """
    Returns the name of the project root directory.

    :return: Project root directory name
    """

    # stack trace history related to the call of this function
    frame_stack: [FrameInfo] = inspect.stack()

    # get info about the module that has invoked this function
    # (index=0 is always this very module, index=1 is fine as long this function is not called by some other
    # function in this module)
    frame_info: FrameInfo = frame_stack[1]

    # if there are multiple calls in the stacktrace of this very module, we have to skip those and take the first
    # one which comes from another module
    if frame_info.filename == __file__:
        for frame in frame_stack:
            if frame.filename != __file__:
                frame_info = frame
                break

    # path of the module that has invoked this function
    caller_path: str = frame_info.filename

    # absolute path of the of the module that has invoked this function
    caller_absolute_path: str = os.path.abspath(caller_path)

    # get the top most directory path which contains the invoker module
    paths: [str] = [p for p in sys.path if p in caller_absolute_path]
    paths.sort(key=lambda p: len(p))
    caller_root_path: str = paths[0]

    if not os.path.isabs(caller_path):
        # file name of the invoker module (eg: "mymodule.py")
        caller_module_name: str = Path(caller_path).name

        # this piece represents a subpath in the project directory
        # (eg. if the root folder is "myproject" and this function has ben called from myproject/foo/bar/mymodule.py
        # this will be "foo/bar")
        project_related_folders: str = caller_path.replace(os.sep + caller_module_name, '')

        # fix root path by removing the undesired subpath
        caller_root_path = caller_root_path.replace(project_related_folders, '')

    dir_name: str = Path(caller_root_path).name

    return dir_name
```

Comment: @dev, whats `inspect` in `inspect.stack()`

Comment: @binrebin [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) - module in Python standard library.

Comment: @daveoncode, i found another thing somewhere. thans for reply

Answer (score 2):

I would take a different approach where i would keep looping while moving up until it locate the .git folder or any other file in the root

```py
import os

def find_project_root(start_dir):
    """Find the root directory of a project containing a .git directory.
    Usage: find_project_root(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    Args:
        start_dir (str): The directory to start the search from."""
    current_dir = start_dir
    while True:
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(current_dir, '.git')):
            return current_dir
        # Move up one directory
        current_dir = os.path.pardir(current_dir)
        # If reached the root directory
        if current_dir == os.path.dirname(current_dir):
            return None

project_root = find_project_root(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
print(project_root)
```

or

simply use this:

```py
import subprocess

project_root = subprocess.run(["git", "rev-parse", "--show-toplevel"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout.replace("\n", "")

print(project_root)
```

Comment: I like the idea, here is a recursive function:

'def find_project_root(current_dir):
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(current_dir, '.git')):
        return current_dir
    else:            
        # Move up one directory
        current_dir = current_dir.parent
        if len(current_dir.parents)<2:
            return None
        
        return find_project_root(current_dir)'

Answer (score 1):

I used the ../ method to fetch the current project path.

Example:
Project1 -- D:\projects

src

ConfigurationFiles

Configuration.cfg

**Path="../src/ConfigurationFiles/Configuration.cfg"**

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this issue.

I have a simple use-case that bugged me for a while. Tried a few solutions, but I didn't like either of them flexible enough.

So here's what I figured out.

- create a blank python file in the root dir -> I call this `beacon.py`
  (assuming that the project root is in the PYTHONPATH so it can be imported)
- add a few lines to my module/class which I call here `not_in_root.py`.
  This will import the `beacon.py` module and get the path to that
  module

Here's an example project structure

```
this_project
├── beacon.py
├── lv1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── lv2
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── not_in_root.py
...
```

The content of the `not_in_root.py`

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path


class Config:
    try:
        import beacon
        print(f"'import beacon' -> {os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(beacon.__file__))}")  # only for demo purposes
        print(f"'import beacon' -> {Path(beacon.__file__).parent.resolve()}")  # only for demo purposes
    except ModuleNotFoundError as e:
        print(f"ModuleNotFoundError: import beacon failed with {e}. "
              f"Please. create a file called beacon.py and place it to the project root directory.")

    project_root = Path(beacon.__file__).parent.resolve()
    input_dir = project_root / 'input'
    output_dir = project_root / 'output'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = Config()
    print(f"Config.project_root: {c.project_root}")
    print(f"Config.input_dir: {c.input_dir}")
    print(f"Config.output_dir: {c.output_dir}")
```

The output would be

```
/home/xyz/projects/this_project/venv/bin/python /home/xyz/projects/this_project/lv1/lv2/not_in_root.py
'import beacon' -> /home/xyz/projects/this_project
'import beacon' -> /home/xyz/projects/this_project
Config.project_root: /home/xyz/projects/this_project
Config.input_dir: /home/xyz/projects/this_project/input
Config.output_dir: /home/xyz/projects/this_project/output
```

Of course, it doesn't need to be called `beacon.py` nor need to be empty, essentially any python file (importable) file would do as long as it's in the root directory.

Using an empty .py file sort of guarantees that it will not be moved elsewhere due to some future refactoring.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The project root directory does not have `__init__.py`.
I solved this problem by looking for an ancestor directory that does not have `__init__.py`.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from pathlib import Path

@lru_cache()
def get_root_dir() -> str:
    path = Path().cwd()
    while Path(path, "__init__.py").exists():
        path = path.parent
    return str(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you can add the root directory of your code repository to the Python path. You can do this by adding the following lines of code at the beginning of your script:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

This code adds the parent directory of the current file (which is assumed to be in a subfolder of the root directory) to the Python path.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with anaconda-project, you can query the PROJECT_ROOT from the environment variable --> os.getenv('PROJECT_ROOT'). This works only if the script is executed via anaconda-project run .

If you do not want your script run by anaconda-project, you can query the absolute path of the executable binary of the Python interpreter you are using and extract the path string up to the envs directory exclusiv. For example: The python interpreter of my conda env is located at:

> /home/user/project_root/envs/default/bin/python

```
# You can first retrieve the env variable PROJECT_DIR.
# If not set, get the python interpreter location and strip off the string till envs inclusiv...

if os.getenv('PROJECT_DIR'):
    PROJECT_DIR = os.getenv('PROJECT_DIR')
else:
    PYTHON_PATH = sys.executable
    path_rem = os.path.join('envs', 'default', 'bin', 'python')
    PROJECT_DIR = py_path.split(path_rem)[0]
```

This works only with conda-project with fixed project structure of a anaconda-project

Answer (score 0):

I ended up needing to do this in various different situations where different answers worked correctly, others didn't, or either with various modifications, so I made this package to work for most situations

```
pip install get-project-root
```

```
    from get_project_root import root_path
    
    project_root = root_path(ignore_cwd=False)
    # >> "C:/Users/person/source/some_project/"
```

https://pypi.org/project/get-project-root/

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to this question; But it might help someone. In fact, if you know the names of the folders, you can do this.

```py
import os
import sys

TMP_DEL = '×'
PTH_DEL = '\\'


def cleanPath(pth):
    pth = pth.replace('/', TMP_DEL)
    pth = pth.replace('\\', TMP_DEL)
    return pth


def listPath():
    return sys.path


def getPath(__file__):
    return os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


def getRootByName(__file__, dirName):
    return getSpecificParentDir(__file__, dirName)


def getSpecificParentDir(__file__, dirName):
    pth = cleanPath(getPath(__file__))
    dirName = cleanPath(dirName)
    candidate = f'{TMP_DEL}{dirName}{TMP_DEL}'
    if candidate in pth:
        pth = (pth.split(candidate)[0]+TMP_DEL +
               dirName).replace(TMP_DEL*2, TMP_DEL)
        return pth.replace(TMP_DEL, PTH_DEL)
    return None


def getSpecificChildDir(__file__, dirName):
    for x in [x[0] for x in os.walk(getPath(__file__))]:
        dirName = cleanPath(dirName)
        x = cleanPath(x)
        if TMP_DEL in x:
            if x.split(TMP_DEL)[-1] == dirName:
                return x.replace(TMP_DEL, PTH_DEL)
    return None
```

List available folders:

```py
print(listPath())
```

Usage:

```py
#Directories
#ProjectRootFolder/.../CurrentFolder/.../SubFolder


print(getPath(__file__))
# c:\ProjectRootFolder\...\CurrentFolder

print(getRootByName(__file__, 'ProjectRootFolder'))
# c:\ProjectRootFolder

print(getSpecificParentDir(__file__, 'ProjectRootFolder'))
# c:\ProjectRootFolder

print(getSpecificParentDir(__file__, 'CurrentFolder'))
# None

print(getSpecificChildDir(__file__, 'SubFolder'))
# c:\ProjectRootFolder\...\CurrentFolder\...\SubFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

#### One-line solution

Hi all! I have been having this issue for ever as well and none of the solutions worked for me, so I used a similar approach that `here::here()` uses in `R`.

1. Install the `groo` package: `pip install groo-ozika`
2. Place a hidden file in your **root directory**, e.g. `.my_hidden_root_file`.
3. Then from anywhere *lower* in the directory hierarchy (i.e. within
   the root) run the following:

```py
from groo.groo import get_root
root_folder = get_root(".my_hidden_root_file")
```

4. That's it!

It just executes the following function:

```py
def get_root(rootfile):
    import os 
    from pathlib import Path
    d = Path(os.getcwd())
    found = 0
    while found == 0:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(d, rootfile)):
            found = 1
        else:
            d=d.parent
    return d
```

Comment: This is over-complicated for most of time, but would work for `pyproject.toml` instead of `.my_hidden_root_file` .

Comment: @KazuyaGosho I disagree on this point - there might be multiple `pyproject.toml` files in the hierarchy, same for `.git` or similar. This is very simple to reproduce and it works from all levels and on all platforms :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has a LOT of answers, but I'd like to share a pretty straightforward method IMO.

Using [python-git-info](https://pypi.org/project/python-git-info/)

You can define and use this function from anywhere inside your project. Simple.

```
def getRoot()->Path:
  """Function to get the root directory path

   Returns:
     Path: Root of project
  """
  import gitinfo
  o:dict = gitinfo.get_git_info()
  repoString = o['gitdir'].split('/')[-2]
  dirList = dir.split("/")
  for i in dirList:
    if dirList[-1]!=repoString:
      dirList.pop()
    else:
      ABPATH = "/".join(dirList)
  return Path(ABPATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution for me is exploring `sys.path` and my own `__file__` value, because the current running module is available in *sys.path for sure*, no matter how it has been imported, so:

```
def get_project_root(cls):
    for path in sys.path:
        r = __file__.split(path)
        if len(r) > 1:
            return path
```

will locate the absolute path of my project root folder, no matter if:

- the current directory where the program is launched isn't related with folder code (i.e. `sys.path[1]` may fail)
- I'm using a launcher such `uvicorn` so `sys.modules['__main__'].__file__` will yield something like `.venv/bin/uvicorn`)
- any other circumstance that may fails above solutions.

I hope it will helps.

Answer (score -1):

There are many answers here but I couldn't find something simple that covers all cases so allow me to suggest my solution too:

```html
import pathlib
import os

def get_project_root():
    """
    There is no way in python to get project root. This function uses a trick.
    We know that the function that is currently running is in the project.
    We know that the root project path is in the list of PYTHONPATH
    look for any path in PYTHONPATH list that is contained in this function's path
    Lastly we filter and take the shortest path because we are looking for the root.
    :return: path to project root
    """
    apth = str(pathlib.Path().absolute())
    ppth = os.environ['PYTHONPATH'].split(':')
    matches = [x for x in ppth if x in apth]
    project_root = min(matches, key=len)
    return project_root
```

Comment: I do not think we know our projects are in the PYTHONPATH path. I can create a shortcut icon for my desktop (Microsoft Windows) that has a "starting directory" that is outside my PYTHONPATH, and I can just open a console, cd to the directory with the Python module and just type it in: python.exe my_root_module.py which would not be in my PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Answer (score -1):

**Important**: This solution requires you to run the file as a module with `python -m pkg.file` and not as a script like `python file.py`.

```py
import sys
import os.path as op
root_pkg_dirname = op.dirname(sys.modules[__name__.partition('.')[0]].__file__)
```

---

Other answers have requirements like depending on an environment variable or the position of another module in the package structure.

As long as you run the script as `python -m pkg.file` (with the `-m`), this approach is self-contained and will work in any module of the package, including in the top-level `__init__.py` file.

```py
import sys
import os.path as op

root_pkg_name, _, _ = __name__.partition('.')
root_pkg_module = sys.modules[root_pkg_name]
root_pkg_dirname = op.dirname(root_pkg_module.__file__)

config_path = os.path.join(root_pkg_dirname, 'configuration.conf')
```

It works by taking the first component in the dotted string contained in `__name__` and using it as a key in `sys.modules` which returns the module object of the top-level package. Its `__file__` attribute contains the path we want after trimming off `/__init__.py` using `os.path.dirname()`.

Comment: Could you add a short description about your solution and how they can use it as their solution?

Comment: `root_pkg_dirname` is the directory where a file is called. It is not always a project root.

Comment: @Nairum The script has to be run as `python -m` for this method to work. I’ve added a note now explaining this.