# Python access to project root directory

Tags: python

Below folder structure of my application:

```
rootfolder
          /subfolder1/
          /subfolder2
          /subfolder3/test.py
```

my code inside of the subfolder3. But I want to write output of the code to `subfolder1`.

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

full_path = os.path.join(script_dir,'/subfolder1/')
```

I would like to know how can I do this wihout importing full path to directory.

Comment: Use relative paths?

Comment: Call `dirname` twice?

Comment: What's actually tripping you up here?

Comment: "wihout importing full path to directory". Barring the typo, where are you importing anything?

Comment: I mean os.path.join('/etc/test/tesfdfd/rootfolder/', '/subfolder1/'). I don't want to do like this.

Comment: Sorry for my silly question. Really my brain stuck now :)

Comment: my second option was like this: 
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dir_path = os.path.dirname(path)
sys.path.append(dir_path)

Comment: So you're OK with the way you have it now, with `script_dir` coming from `__file__`?

Comment: but it didn't work also

Comment: Why would you append anything to `sys.path`? That won't change your script output, just where you import modules from.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the problem is I am not OK :)

Comment: I have done above. I don't know why it can't find folder in sys.path

Comment: `full_path = os.path.join(script_dir, os.pardir, 'subfolder1')` if you're running the script directly from `rootfolder/subfolder3/`.

Comment: @zwer thanks again I got No such file or directory

Comment: What do you get when you do: `print(os.path.abspath(__file__))` instead?

Comment: script home folder with file

Comment: @QaqaLeveo. Unless you show some concrete examples of the paths that you are dealing with, it is very difficult to solve your problem for you. Given the structure that you have shown here, I am unable to reproduce the issue. Also, please show how you run the script. Is it from the same directory or from another directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Get path of root project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you want something along the lines of

```
project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
output_path = os.path.join(project_root, 'subfolder1')
```

The `project_root` is set to the folder *above* your script's parent folder, which matches your description. The output folder then goes to `subfolder1` under that.

I would also rephrase my import as

```
from os.path import dirname, join
```

That shortens your code to

```
project_root = dirname(dirname(__file__))
output_path = join(project_root, 'subfolder1')
```

I find this version to be easier to read.

Comment: Print the intermediate results: `__file__`, `project_root` and `output_path`. Make sure they are correct.

Comment: all of them under my hand. Really can't understand what is wrong with this. All of them seems true

Comment: I mean show me the printouts. I want to be able to diagnose this.

Comment: `project_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))` only returns `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Jakob. What version of python are you using, and where is the module stored?

Comment: @MadPhysicist. Python version is 3.9.16 and if you with module mean the python path, it's in a Conda environment under `/Users/username/miniconda3/envs/conda_env/bin/python`. The project (and where I run the code from) is located under `/Users/username/Desktop/Projects/project_name` though.

Comment: Hmm, okay. I tested it in a jupyter notebook (`.ipynb`) and that didn't work. It works in a `.py` file though.

Answer (score -2):

The best way to get this done is to turn your project into a module.  Python uses an `__init__.py` file to recognize this setup.  So we can simply create an empty `__init__.py` file at the root directory.  The structure would look like:

```
rootfolder
          /subfolder1/
          /subfolder2
          /subfolder3/test.py
          __init__.py
```

Once that is done, you can reference any subfolders like the following:

```
subfolder1/output.txt
```

Therefore, your script would look something like this:

```
f = open("subfolder1/output.txt", "w+")
f.write("works!")
f.close()
```

Comment: `__init__` makes it a package, not a module. You will then need an `__init__` in `subfolder3` to mark it as a sub-package. None of this, however, will affect where you put your output data. Also, use `with` to open files.

Comment: You're right, my fault!  Marking subfolder3 as a sub-package isn't needed for this though.

Comment: The reference won't magically resolve itself unless you run from a very specific directory. That is why OP is using `__file__` and why having an `__init__` or not having it is totally irrelevant.