# opoening data using pandas in python 3.7

Tags: python, database, pandas

hi i tried  to open some data that i downloaded to my documents  using pandas with python 3.7 
but it doesnt work 
this is my code :

```
    import pandas as pd
    users=pd.read_csv("ml-100k/u.user",sep="|",names=["User ID","Age","Gender", 
    "aciation" ,"zipcode"])
    user.head()
```

the eror is :

```
    FileNotFoundError: File b'ml-100k/u.user' does not exist
```

how can it be that the file doesnt exist if i downloaded it ?
thaks:)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're getting a byte string, but that's a relative path so it matters what directory you're in when you run that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is that your data file is not in the path of your python session. There are a few ways to fix this.

- First, your file has `.user` extension. I believe it should be a `.csv` extension for pd.read_csv(). Rename the file to make sure the extension and the name of the file are correct. I also advise to make the filename code friendly, substitute whitespaces for `_` or `-` and remove non-alphanumeric characters `#*/()`.
- One solution is to provide the full path to the pd.read_csv() function.

  ```
  pd.read_csv("/home/user/folder/file_name.csv",
              sep="|",names=["User ID","Age","Gender","aciation" ,"zipcode"])
  ```
- If you are using ipython or jupyter notebook you can navigate to the same folder where your file is at with `cd path_to_file_folder` command and simply pass the file name to the command:

  ```
  pd.read_csv("file_name.csv",sep="|",
              names=["User ID","Age","Gender","aciation" ,"zipcode"])
  ```

For more robust solutions check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure).