# Python - Including python scripts from project root in setup.py build

Tags: python, build, setup.py

I already had a look at the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52937779/including-python-file-from-project-root-in-setup-py-build) but I was not able to understand which is the solution...

I'm trying to write a setup.py file to build my code.

Here is the directory structure of the project:

```
project
|
├── setup.py
|
├── MANIFEST.in
|
├── package1
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── data.py
    |__ file.yml
    └── util_folder
├── package2
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── tool.py
    └── utils.py  
|___ script1.py
|___ script2.py
```

Here the main content of setup.py

```
setup(
     name = "MyProject",
     packages=['package1','package2'],
     include_package_data=True,
)
```

Here my MANIFEST.in to also include the util_folder under package1 and the two scripts located at the root folder.

```
include *.py
recursive-include package1 *
```

However, after running

```
python setup.py install
```

in my conda env, script1.py and script2.py are not copied to the destination, i.e.

```
path/to/my/conda/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MyProject-1.0-py3.7.egg/
```

Under that location I can see only package1 and package2.

What's wrong?

Comment: You might need either `py_modules` or `scripts`, depending on what the intention is. Should `script1` and `script2` be importable or executable?

Comment: Both scripts should be imported

Comment: Then use `py_modules`. Also I would not call these files _scripts_, but _modules_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you should probably do something like:

```py
import setuptools
setuptools.setup(
    # ...
    py_modules=[
        'script1',
        'script2',
    ],
)
```

Note than in such a case the preferred denomination is *module*, instead of *script*. From my point of view *scripts* are meant to be called and executed directly, and modules are meant to be imported.