# Python equivalent of R "here" package

Tags: python

Is there a Python equivalent for this library?

https://github.com/r-lib/here/

Comment: I am not sure of your use-case but you might be looking for virtualenv's ?

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure

Comment: Look into virutalenvs/Conda and you can go from there

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like someone had the same problem:

https://github.com/chendaniely/pyprojroot