# How to get project's root path inside my package?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create one distributable package in Python.So in my package I need to access a file from the root of the project for which my package is installed inside. I am trying to do that like this,

```
Path(__file__).parents[1] / Path(self.file_name)
```

But is is just returning '.' which means it indicating my package's root folder.
For example my package directory structure looks like this,

```
mypackage
 - lib
   - myfile.py
 - __init__.py
```

So when I convert that package to installable wheel format I can install that using pip command.If now I create project like this,

```
myproject
 - __init__.py
 - config.json
 - main.py
 - venv
```

Now see I want to use/install `mypackage` in `myproject`. All the packages are installed inside the `venv` folder. So now my question is how I can access the `config.json` file inside my `mypackage`. So to do that I require to access the root folder of `myproject`.I hope this is clear to understand.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: . is the "current working directory". It is a proper path.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I know but that is my package directory. When I install my package for any project I want that project's root directory.

Comment: This statement '*So now my question is how I can access the config.json file inside my mypackag*' doesn't match your graph. The 'config.json' seems under your project directory instead of your package in your graph.

Comment: That is my problem statement. I want to access `config.json` file which is inside the `myproject` dir not in `mypackage` dir.

Comment: Do you need the actual path or just the content of the JSON? Is `myproject` a package itself? The `__init__.py` suggests yes, the venv suggests no. Put another way: what do you consider "a project"? Python has no such concept.

Comment: If I have access to the `myproject` dir then I can read the any file I want but yes my main goal is to read the `config.json` file. `mypackage` is a python package I am trying to create.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Get path of root project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources) to access file-like resources in packages. This uses the import machinery to locate the resource, ensuring that you get the resource in the package used by your program.
For example, if you want the resource as a file:

```py
import importlib.resources
import json

# create a pathlib.Path pointing to the resource
with importlib.resources.path("myproject", "config.json") as json_path:
    with json_path.open() as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
```

Using `importlib` will work for any importable package, including those not backed by the filesystem (e.g. a zipped package). Note that if you are just interested in the contents, then `importlib.resources.read_text` is more convenient instead of creating a file just to discard it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but one question `myproject` can have any name so in that case how I would I know that. I just can't hard code the project name in my package.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi In that case, treating it as "the JSON inside ``myproject``" is the entirely wrong approach. As mentioned in the question comments, there plainly is no such thing as "a project", only packages – what you consider "a project" is not well-defined enough for code to find it. It seems logically the JSON is just *some* JSON and ``mypackage`` should make no attempt at all to locate it – it should be *given* the location of either "the project" or the JSON.

Comment: So the conclusion is that it is not possible to achieve that in python.

Comment: The conclusion is that you should clearly define what your setup is – including which parts are happenstance and which are deliberate.

Comment: Which part you don't understand?Let me put it this way,Pandas is a well know library/package which can be installed in your project. In the same manner I am trying to create one standalone package which I can use in any of my "project". I create one venv and install my that package, So my package needs to have access to a file which resides inside that project.Hope this make sense to you.

Comment: @RopAliMunshi Mostly the word "project" makes no sense for Python. Consider that "a well known library/package" like Pandas has *no* concept of being installed into a project – you *don't* install package into projects, you install them into the module search path. What is a project? Some IDE folder? A working directory? The directory in which a venv root is?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, a python script in the root directory will import your package. If this is correct, the following code may help:

```
import os
import __main__ as main
if hasattr(main, '__file__'):
    root_dir = os.path.dirname(main.__file__)
```

Comment: I have updated my question to make it more clear. Please go through it.

Comment: From your updated question, your app is main.py and the code above will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
import os
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) # This is your Project Root
```

and see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25389715/1010493) as reference , it will help you

Comment: It will always give me the root folder of the file where my code is not the project's root folder.