# How to get absolute path of root directory from anywhere within the directory in python

Tags: python, directory

Let's say I have the following directory

```
model_folder
|
|
------- model_modules
|            |
|             ---- __init__.py
|            |
|             ---- foo.py
|            |
|             ---- bar.py
|
|
------- research
|            |
|            ----- training.ipynb
|            |
|            ----- eda.ipynb
|
|
------- main.py
```

and I want to import `model_modules` into a script in `research`

I can do that with the following

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/absolute/path/model_folder')
from model_modules.foo import Foo
from model_modules.bar import Bar
```

However, let's say I don't explicitly know the absolute path of the root, or perhaps just don't want to hardcode it as it may change locations. How could I get the absolute path of `module_folder` from anywhere in the directory so I could do something like this?

```
import sys
sys.path.append(root)
from model_modules.foo import Foo
from model_modules.bar import Bar
```

I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure) in which one of the answers recommends adding the following to the root directory, like so:

```
utils.py
from pathlib import Path

def get_project_root() -> Path:
    return Path(__file__).parent.parent
```

```
model_folder
|
|
------- model_modules
|            |
|             ---- __init__.py
|            |
|             ---- foo.py
|            |
|             ---- bar.py
|
|
|
------- src
|        |
|         ---- utils.py
|
|
|
|
|
------- research
|            |
|            ----- training.ipynb
|            |
|            ----- eda.ipynb
|
|
------- main.py
```

But then when I try to import this into a script in a subdirectory, like `training.ipynb`, I get an error

```
from src.utils import get_project_root
root = get_project_root

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

So my question is, how can I get the absolute path to the root directory from anywhere within the directory in python?

Comment: A good solution would be to add `model_folder` to your $PYTHONPATH environment variable.  Then you can import any of its subdirectories without worry.

Answer (score 0):

sys.path[0] contain your root directory (the directory where the program is located). You can use that to add your sub-directories.

```
import sys
sys.path.append( sys.path[0] + "/model_modules")
import foo
```

and for cases where foo.py may exist elsewhere:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert( 1, sys.path[0] + "/model_modules") # put near front of list
import foo
```