# Appropriate python project setup for accessing paths relative to the project root folder out of a module in src

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

Example project structure:

```
|-setup.toml
|-README.md
|-tests/...
|-data/...
|-src/
   |-package1
   |-package2
         |-module1.py
   |-package3
         |-subpackage4
                |-module2.py
```

In reality, I have many more folders and files scattered around them and I need to be able to access `$ROOT/data/...` from most of them. Ideally, I wouldn't have to update numerous strings across the project every time I decide to move the file from one folder to another.

I can think of a number of solutions but none of them seem clean.

For example, I could `pip install -e` the package and have a module at the top level (just under `src/`) which would `import os` so I would just need to add `../data/` on top of that root. Then, I would import this module in all the other `py` files throughout the directory structure.

I think it would do the job but it feels very clumsy, surely there is a better way?

Looked through lots of documentation for setuptools, poetry etc. but none of the tutorials cover this trivial scenario. They are mostly concerned with dependencies and publishing to `PyPi`.

Is this still the way to do this in 2023?
[Python - Get path of root project structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389095/python-get-path-of-root-project-structure)

Comment: Data files have to be part of an importable package in order to avoid a lot of inconveniences. I recommend you move `$ROOT/data` to `$ROOT/src/packagedata` for example, and make sure that this `packagedata` gets installed and is importable.

Comment: The code produces the data(sets) and there is a lot of data so it's not to be packaged with the code (it is also exclude from git etc.)

Comment: Ah... Then I would recommend to place this data in one of the directories handled by something like [*`platformdirs`*](https://pypi.org/project/platformdirs/).

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. And what would be a clean way to allow the user to customise their own folder instead? Also, would you still create a single `definitions.py` that will call platformdirs once and then import that everywhere else or would you invoke platformdirs everywhere directly?

Comment: Uh, that's a different set of questions, but OK... ***1.*** You can have a configuration file in the `user_config_dir` that contains a field where the user has to write the path where to store the data, or you can make it a mandatory parameter to your CLI (or whatever application you have). ***2.*** I guess maybe I would write a helper function that I can reuse instead of calling `platformdirs` from multiple places throughout my code, but really it does not matter much.

Comment: I tried creating an `.env` file with `ROOT=$(pwd)` but `os.environ['ROOT']` returns `"$(pwd)"`. I also tried creating `definitions.py` at the end but even after running `poetry install` I am not able to import this module from the nested directories (even though VS code is able to auto-complete it). What am I missing..